# Random if/else behavior - Rock, Paper, Scissors game

Tags: javascript

So I have been working on this for awhile and can't figure out why my if/else statement does not console.log the correct response based on the computer and player selections. **It seems like it will return a random statement regardless of the input from player or computer. Also, I don't understand why it will prompt me for input twice.**

I get that there are other ways to build a simple RPS game in the console, but I don't understand why this won't work specifically. I'm more worried about what steps I'm missing in building a simple game that are essential for other projects later. I'm obviously new at this and am working on this through the Odin Project website, for reference. Thank you so much in advance for the help! Anyway, here's the code:

```
  <script>
    function computerChoice() {
      let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
      let result = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
      return result
    };

    let playerSelection = function() {
      let playerChoice = prompt('What do you choose, young Padawan?')
      return playerChoice.toLowerCase()
    };

    let computerSelection = computerChoice();

    console.log(computerChoice());
    console.log(playerSelection());

    function play(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
      if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        console.log('Paper beats rock! Computron wins!');
      } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
        console.log('Rock smash scissors! You win!');
      } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
        console.log('Paper covers rock! You win Starlord!');
      } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
        console.log('Scissors cuts paper! Thanos is king!'); 
      } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        console.log('Scissors cuts paper! The Avengers avenge!'); 
      } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
        console.log('Rock smash! Avengers suck!');
      } else {
        console.log('Tie! You must select a different weapon!');
        }   
    };

      play();

  </script>
```

Comment: Your computer selection and the console.log value are from two seperate calls to the `computerChoice()` function so will likely be different values.

Comment: You define `play` as having two arguments but you invoke with 0

Comment: `playerSelection` is the function, not the returned value

Comment: @Scrimothy, yeah I noticed that too. If you want the value just put the console log before the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a combination of different ways of defining and calling function here.  You define your player selection function but do not call it in a single instance, like you do with your computer selection.  To make the player selection be consistent for the results, define your player selection as a function and then assign the results to a variable before logging it.

```js
function computerChoice() {
  let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  let result = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  return result
};

function playerChoice() {
  let playerChoice = prompt('What do you choose, young Padawan?');
  return playerChoice.toLowerCase();
}

let playerSelection = playerChoice();
let computerSelection = computerChoice();

console.log("Player selection", playerSelection);
console.log("Computer selection", computerSelection);

function play(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    console.log('Paper beats rock! Computron wins!');
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    console.log('Rock smash scissors! You win!');
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    console.log('Paper covers rock! You win Starlord!');
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    console.log('Scissors cuts paper! Thanos is king!'); 
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    console.log('Scissors cuts paper! The Avengers avenge!'); 
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    console.log('Rock smash! Avengers suck!');
  } else {
    console.log('Tie! You must select a different weapon!');
  }   
};

play(playerSelection, computerSelection);
```

**EDIT**

Also, you define two parameters for your play function but never pass them in to the function, make sure you pass in both playerSelection and computerSelection

Comment: This answer is the most straight-forward and true to the OP's logic. Nice job focusing only on the lightest touch changes and explanations

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick replies! So in cases like this, would it be wise/necessary to remove function names from parameters like you did (which I guess keeps the function from being called again) by having them assigned to each other (computerSelection = computerChoice)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean but maybe this will explain it.  `function computerChoice()` and `let playerSelection = function()` are both ways of creating a function.  `let playerSelection = function()` does not assign the result of the function to a variable, it sets the function itself to a variable so it can be called in the future.  If you want to use the result of a function in multiple places (such as a `console.log` and the parameter for a function) you must call the function and assign it to a variable.  Then in future calls, just use that variable name.

Comment: for example `console.log(computerChoice())` will give a random output every time you call it because you are calling the function inside of the `console.log`.  If you assign a variable to a call of the `computerChoice` function `let cc = computerChoice()` then every time you use the `cc` variable it will refer to the result of that specific function call.  I'm not sure if I'm explaining this simply enough so let me know if you have any more questions!

Answer (score 0):

You were calling your function with `console.log`, I added a promise to make sure nothing runs until user input is selected. Then showed you were to restart if it is a tie.

```
console.log(computerChoice()); // re-runs function
console.log(playerSelection()); // re-runs function
```

I also make sure the page is loaded before we start throwing some alerts to the user for curtesy.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { })
```

For computerChoice function let's remove the redundant variable, since we are returning what the variable value is. We do this instead.

```
return (choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]);
```

We used a promise for the user input, a promise basically is a function that promises a value or rejects something. When you call the function, you use `.then((value))` to get the value.

```
let playerSelection = function() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let playerChoice = prompt('What do you choose, young Padawan?')
        console.log(playerChoice); // we log the player choice here instead
        resolve(playerChoice.toLowerCase());
      })
};
```

We get the promise value like this

```
playerSelection().then((value) => {  })
```

```js
function computerChoice() {
        let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
        return (choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]);

      }

    let playerSelection = function() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let playerChoice = prompt('What do you choose, young Padawan?')
        console.log(playerChoice); // we log the player choice here instead
        resolve(playerChoice.toLowerCase());
      })
    };

    // Remove console.log(playerChoice); calling the function, causes two prompts

    function play() {
      playerSelection().then((playerChoice) => {
        let computerSelection = computerChoice(); // We want new one each time.
        if (playerChoice === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
          console.log('Paper beats rock! Computron wins!');
        } else if (playerChoice === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
          console.log('Rock smash scissors! You win!');
        } else if (playerChoice === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
          console.log('Paper covers rock! You win Starlord!');
        } else if (playerChoice === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
          console.log('Scissors cuts paper! Thanos is king!');
        } else if (playerChoice === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
          console.log('Scissors cuts paper! The Avengers avenge!');
        } else if (playerChoice === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
          console.log('Rock smash! Avengers suck!');
        } else {
          alert('Tie! You must select a different weapon!');
          play() // Tie-have user re-enter choice
        }
      })
    };
    // Make sure page loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      //do work
      play();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I didn't even know promises were a thing; I'll have to do some reading up on them! And another quick question: is the "DOMContentLoaded" an in-built part of javascript? I just wasn't sure where it was coming from/what was its purpose. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes it is built in.